# Why can't I use the rectangular selection tool outside of my canvas?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools, selections, slices

I have a PSD with a mobile and Desktop artboard in it, working in the latest version of Photoshop CC.

I'm trying to make slices out of layers, but one layer in particular runs off the canvas, so I'm trying to just clip the layer by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+selecting it, then with the rectangular selection tool and holding <kbd>ALT</kbd> I drag a box off canvas to begin removing the off-canvas sections of the rectangular layer.

However, I can only get the rectangle select tool to work if I place my cursor directly over the canvas, or between the two artboards.  If I try this anywhere outside of the canvas that isn't directly between the two artboards it fails.

Why is this?

Comment: Originally there was nothing outside the canvas so id say this is a legacy feature

Comment: Wait a sec, your object runs off _canvas_ or off _artboard_? I think you're mixing up terms and those are different elements. I don't think you can select anything that runs off the _canvas_, as opposed to objects that are _off the artboards into the canvas_.

Comment: @Luciano  I meant exactly what I said.  When I say in-between two art boards (Mobile vs Desktop in this case) then it works.  If my cursor isn't between the two art boards and is located outside of the canvas then I cannot create a selection box regardless of whether I am holding Shift (to add), Alt (to subtract) or neither.